# Matlab Simulink graph plotting

Tags: matlab, simulink

I plotted a signal using "To Workspace" in Simulink Matlab. Now I want to take the mean of the specific part of that signal which I plotted.How can I extract values from "To Workspace" or how can I take the mean of the specific area of that graph.

Comment: variables "To Workspace" goes to... workspace. You should find it there...

Answer (score 3):

In "To workspace" you define a variable name, let's say: "simout"
I made a simple simulink as the following:

[image]

you can save with different formats: Timeseries, Structure with time, Structure, Array. 
Then, when you run the simulink, it will save the variable in the worksapce as a structure.
Then you can use the variable to plot the data inside. check this example :
consider you saved using Structure with time you can get data like this:

```
t = simout.time
x = simout.signals.values
```

and you can plot the data:

```
plot(t,x)
```

Comment: thank you soo much for your reply, but i am already using save format " ARRAY" because i need arrays and then i have to use these arrays to plot the graph and i already plotted the graph but now i want to take the specific portion of plotted graph to take the mean of that portion. waiting for your reply. Thanks alot...